# ClaimCenter Web PCF files UI Labels

Tags: user-interface, label, pcf, guidewire

I’m trying to automate building of a mapping document between claimcenter gui through to dB. I’ve made some success in this space using the data dictionary however I’ve become a bit stumped when it gets to getting labels for the UI fields

I’ve been looking at the web pcf files and I can see where labels are mentioned for UI fields, for example

```
label="DisplayKey.get(&quot; VehicleIncident.Audatex.AudatexLV.AudatexReference &quot;)"
```

I assume this is making a call someplace to get the description and populate it?

Would anyone know where this might be and perhaps where I should look to next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In properly configured guidewire studio, those should be properly resolved on CRTL+left mouse button on the label in the DisplayKey.get function call.

If they are not then it is resolving them to

> modules\configuration\config\locale\display_en_US.properties

If your locale is different then en_US might be something else.